# Golang Antlr cannot find path for parser

Tags: go, antlr

I am trying to use a Golang parser generated by Antlr. but when I try to access it in my main file, it gives me the following error: `build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path path/to/parser` my main file is this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "./parser"
    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
    is := antlr.NewInputStream("1 + 2 * 3")

    // Create the Lexer
    lexer := parser.NewHelloWorldLexer(is)

    // Read all tokens
    for {
        t := lexer.NextToken()
        if t.GetTokenType() == antlr.TokenEOF {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s (%q)\n",
            lexer.SymbolicNames[t.GetTokenType()], t.GetText())
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the project structure and `./parser`

Comment: did you created your project with `go mod` or you are using standard layout

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using go modules

Your project structure should look like this

```
.
├── go.mod
├── main.go
└── parser
    └── parser.go
```

go.mod

```
module example.com/projectname

go 1.15
...
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "example.com/projectname/parser"

    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"
)
...
```

parser.go

```
package parser

import (
    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"
)
...
```

Comment: I fixed this by making a new folder that just has parser capitolized